# How to get iTunes Match to match correctly on boxed sets?

Tags: itunes, itunes-match, id3-tag

Here's a concrete example: The Beatles Mono and Stereo remastered box sets from 2009. How do I ensure each is:

1. matched to a box set, not individual albums.
2. matched to the correct mono or stereo edition.

I ripped and tagged using EAC and Musicbrainz Picard, and the tagging and naming is in the style of a multi-disc set. i.e.:

`8-02 The Beatles - With a Little Help From My Friends.m4a`

I haven't taken the plunge with these and other boxed sets because I've read in many forums that Match butchers them. I'm curious if someone has discovered a safe(r) method.

Comment: You cannot do this. The matching algorithm resides on Apple's side and as a user, you have no control over this. The only thing you can do is let iTunes Match make the attempt, delete your local files (for any file that is marked a match) and verify it is the correct song. If it's not, you will need to file a report with the iTunes Team and report the issue. But keep in mind that at this time, you will likely receive a generic reply stating they are aware of the problem and working on a fix.

Comment: Thanks @cksum. I am aware that the matching algorithm is a black box, but I was hoping someone had figured out this boxed set issue by trial and error. Most of the threads I saw on it were almost a year old...